# Does Electrum support Ledger Nano?

Tags: electrum, hardware-wallet, ledger-hardware-wallet

When you create a new wallet, there are 4 options, one being 'hardware wallet'. However, there is no mention of hardware wallets in the docs!
http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/search.html?q=hardware&check_keywords=yes&area=default

[image: electrum wallet selection]

How do it work? Does it communicate to the hardware wallet with a special protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. There's a [detailed guide on the Ledger site](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005161925-How-to-use-Electrum-with-your-Nano-S), and a bunch of videos on [youtube](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjcxrfd-YDYAhUW8mMKHX7lCZMQtwIILjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwfuvuvCZYEE&usg=AOvVaw0F8JHl4ApbAo5oyiApuy2j) explaining how to use your Ledger with a Electrum.